# How to get redirection to not redirect to 404 page?

Tags: 404-error, redirect

I have a client, who has a page, that has links like site-url/profiles/username/

But instead of passing the username on the url parameter and used to query database, to get profile info, it somehow automatically redirects to 404 page.

They are using the redirection plugin, but there are no entries for this page.

I can pass the username like this site-url/profiles/?user=username

But it is far from the pretty result they are used to.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Any suggestions or tips?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is around parts of "somehow" and "redirection plugin" here. :) I doubt anyone can just _guess_ it. What is the specific plugin? Had you tried contacting its developers/support about the issue?

Comment: Added the name of the plugin used in the question, and thank you.